# How to load url of phonegap in native webview not in cordova webview?

Tags: android, cordova, webview, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to load url inside my custom webview

webview.xml-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativeview" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"  >
<ScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is my classfile

```
public class AppDev extends CordovaActivity implements WLInitWebFrameworkListener {

private WebView webview;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    WL.createInstance(this);

    WL.getInstance().showSplashScreen(this);

    WL.getInstance().initializeWebFramework(getApplicationContext(), this);
    webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);


}
public void onInitWebFrameworkComplete(WLInitWebFrameworkResult result){
    if (result.getStatusCode() == WLInitWebFrameworkResult.SUCCESS) {
    //  super.loadUrl(WL.getInstance().getMainHtmlFilePath());// 
        webview.loadUrl(WL.getInstance().getMainHtmlFilePath());
    } else {
        handleWebFrameworkInitFailure(result);
    }}
```

loading url in webview is producing following error-

```
com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler
java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(com.AppDev.AppDev.onInitWebFrameworkCo    mplete(AppDev.java:49)
```

is there anyway to load url in custom webview not in cordova?
Any Help :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you try following the [Integrating Server Generated Pages in Hybrid Applications training module](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/10_07_Integrating_server_generated_pages_in_Worklight_applications.pdf) and [sample application](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/IncludeExternalPagesProject.zip)?

The module explains how to bring up a webview and display an external website in it (and return back to the application's webview).